# What to name a method

Tags: c#

I'm debating what to name this method.

CloseCashTransaction(Cash.Id, -1, true);

or

CompleteCashTransaction(Cash.Id, -1, true);

or neither are good?

In business terms/process by sending in these 3 values I'm essentially "closing the transaction" or "completing the transaction" in our workflow.

However on the developer side, I cant' infer wtf "Complete" or "Close" means.  It forces me to look into the internals of the method.  My struggle is that I try to name methods to infer what they are doing.  Complete is just way too general and forces the consumer of the method to dive into the code every time I use words like this.

When I see stuff like this all over code, I have to take so much time to figure out what they are actually doing.  And if the comments suck, I end up having to look at all logic in that method because the comments nor the method name really infer what's going on.

Comment: What is the type named in which the method appears?

Comment: From a domain model (i.e. transaction processing) point of view, what does "completing" the transaction do? Does it finalise the movement of funds, for example? If possible, I'd suggest using a term that's relevant from the domain being developed against.

Comment: How about `GetTheMonies(...)`?

Comment: Yes it would finalize the movement of funds in this case.

Comment: But then I feel if I make my names domain driven I end up with a cluster F* of weird names that only people who know the particular business process or workflow for that name would understand which method to use!

Comment: why would people who don't know the business process or workflow be poking around in your code?

Comment: Because there are a LOT of business processes.  I mean common.  Do you think every developer works on every project or knows every business domain or workflow?  Not realistic at all.

Comment: I know it might sound silly, but that is not the case where the comments would actually help? I mean, if the code head its signature well documented, the use of the method would be well understood even from intelisense.

Answer (score 7):

From C# coding standards....

6.8 Methods
Methods should be named using the following format:

Verb + Adjective(s) + Noun + Qualifier(s)

Example:

```
private Ball FindRedCansByPrice( 
     float price, 
  ref int canListToPopulate,
     out int numberOfCansFound )
```

Guidelines:

- Parameters should be grouped by their
  mutability (from least to most
  mutable) as shown in the example
  above.
- If at all possible, avoid exiting methods from their middles.  A well
  written method should only exit from
  one point: at its end.
- Avoid large methods. As a method’s body approaches 20 to 30
  lines of code, look for blocks that
  could be split into their own methods
  and possibly shared by other methods.
- If you find yourself using the same block of code more than once,
  it’s a good candidate for a separate
  method.
- Group like methods within a class together into a region and order them by frequency of use (i.e. more frequently called methods should be near the top of their regions.

Hope it helps

---

**BONUS**

**Naming Parts & Pairs**

1. Common Adjective Pairs

   - Old…/New…
   - Source…/Destination…
   - Source…/Target…
   - First…/Next…/Current…/Previous…/Last…
   - Min…/Max…
2. Common Property Prefixes

   - Allow… (Allows…)
   - Can…
   - Contains…
   - Has…
   - Is…
   - Use… (Uses…)
3. Common Verb Pairs

   - Add…/Remove…
   - Insert…/Delete…
   - Increment/…Decrement…
   - Lock…/Unlock…
   - Begin…/End…
   - Fetch…/Store…
   - To…/From… (Convert implied)
   - Open…/Close…
   - Create…/Destroy…
   - Acquire…/Release…
   - Up…/Down…
   - Show…/Hide…
   - Start…/Stop…
4. Common Qualifiers Suffixes

   - …Avg
   - …Limit
   - …Count
   - …Ref
   - …Entry
   - …Sum
   - …Index
   - …Total

**Note:** Avoid using Num because of semantics; use Index and Count instead. Also, avoid using Temp; take the time to describe what the object really is (e.g. use SwapValue instead of TempValue).

Comment: So, both suggestions are valid according to your guidelines? :)

Comment: So does this go for domain driven development as well??  Anyone??

Comment: for DDD it still works. just make use of a well defined namespaces.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my feedback

- Boolean parameters are generally speaking evil.  As a casual observer I look at your method see `true` and have absolutely no idea what that means.  Instead of a boolean you should either have 2 methods or use an enum instead.  I wrote a more detailed discussion of this issue on my blog ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/01/23/boolean-parameters.aspx))
- The use of -1 here is similar to the use of the boolean in that it adds no value to the reader.  Instead use a named constant or a method with a different name and remove the parameter altogether.

Comment: +1.  it feels like there should be several methods with the various combinations.

Comment: +1, especially for the "Booleans are evil" part.

Comment: I read your article.  I don't get your example.  Are you saying recursive is a boolean or enum?  So if that method is private, then how would your code know whether it should be true/false in any situation?  I may be totally reading your blog post wrong so can you maybe clarify for me?  I understand about the true/false looking confusing when being passed.  I just don't understand your answer with the private..because I don't understand what types you have defined in your params for your example methods in that blog post.

Comment: Yup.  I see two magic values whose purpose isn't self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

What is the class that these methods are on?  What do the parameters do?  Some context would be good...

Why not have a `CashTransaction` class  (or a `ITransaction` interface and a `CashTransaction` implementation) which has a `Close` method or a `Complete` method?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the method cannot easily be chosen without knowing the name of the class, and the pattern of calls you expect to make.

If the Class is named "CashTransaction" and created and then "closed" then:

```
CashTransaction transaction = new CashTransaction();
...
transaction.close(...);
```

seems very natural.

If the class is named "CashTransaction" and it is created, initiated, and completed, then:

```
CashTransaction transaction = new CashTransaction();
...
transaction.initiate(...);
transaction.complete(...);
```

would also be very natural.

Try using your own code, and name the methods based on the context of the class name and call pattern you allow.  Even if that doesn't make the best name to pick much clearer, at least you will be able to document an example of idealized usage in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

What about passing an enum type, as a parameter, to the method :-

```
// declares the enum
public enum Action
{
   Close,
   Complete,
   Open,
   ...
}
```

Usage :-

```
ExecuteTransaction(Cash.Id, -1, true, Action.Close);
```

or

```
ExecuteTransaction(Cash.Id, -1, true, Action.Complete);
```

Comment: I disagree - few smaller methods are better then one big I-will-do-it-all method

Answer (score 0):

Something someone told me may help: "Name things (methods, classes, etc) so that if the business owner had a look at the code, it would make sense to them."

With Intellisense there's no excuse not to properly name things descriptively enough so that a BA or business-type person could understand what it does.

And there's always method/class attributes to further explain to devs should exciting things be happening therein.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with **CloseCashTransaction** mainkly because verb Complete is used in Async calls and your method isn't one.

But the best option is to create CashTransaction class as your code looks like it is written in C, not C#. For better guide look at Edwin Buck's post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm way out in left field, but what about (leaving aside the method arguments which others have commented on):

```
SettlePayment(Cash.Id, -1, true);
```

or

```
SettleCashPayment(Cash.Id, -1, true);
```

I would tend to avoid the use of Transaction in the name since that could be an overloaded term that could cause confusion.  And I agree that Close and Complete are pretty vague.

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I'd go with the shorter name cause I'm lazy.

Seriously though, what to name a method is the least of your worries. Just be sure you have a `///summary`  bit describing it.

Don't forget you can always refactor. VS2008 has a built in refactoring tool to rename methods, so if you don't like it later it literally takes like 10 seconds to rename it.

Comment: Though its not easy, naming methods informatively is one of the most important things you can do to make your code easily understandable

Comment: @Earlz: I respectfully disagree. Naming your methods correctly is *extremely* important. Far more important than commenting them.